# AppleScript to Delete Folder

Tags: applescript

I was wondering if anyone can give me some advice on how I can use apple script to delete this folder?

Users/user1/Library/Application Support/Skype/tankitan

Comment: Why would you need a apple script? is it a repetitive action (you use it more then once?)

Answer (score 5):

```
tell application "Finder" to delete ((POSIX file "/Users/user1/Library/Application Support/Skype/tankitan") as alias)
```

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps this script clears up any 'tankitan' hooks while managing a specific external hook (s), for certain user1 or username (s)

```
(* Ashley Rhodes https://mrashrhodes.wordpress.com/2015/03/18/simple-delete-files-and-folders-script-applescript/ *)
tell application "System Events"
    set deleted to POSIX file "/Users/username/Library/Caches/"
    tell application "Finder"
        delete (files of folder deleted)
        delete (folders of folder deleted)
    end tell
    set deleted to POSIX file "/Users/username/Library/Cookies/"
    tell application "Finder"
        delete (files of folder deleted)
        delete (folders of folder deleted)
    end tell
    set deleted to POSIX file "/Users/username/Library/Saved Application State/"
    tell application "Finder"
        delete (files of folder deleted)
        delete (folders of folder deleted)
    end tell
    set deleted to POSIX file "Users/user1/Library/Application Support/Skype/tankitan"
    tell application "Finder"
        delete (files of folder deleted)
        delete (folders of folder deleted)
    end tell
end tell
```

Mind you, even a [Rhodes](https://mrashrhodes.wordpress.com/2015/03/18/simple-delete-files-and-folders-script-applescript/comment-page-1/#comment-9) POSIX can get tangled...
Managing [sticky-web](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201583) c/o Internet of Things